# Import Only Matched Data From CSV to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

i need to import some data from very huge csv file which is about 1GB.

instead of importing all, i want to just import matched data, i think it will be more easy and faster than importing all data.

i need to search "Post Code District" column of CSV file, if it contains LS1 or LS2 or LS10, import matched data into tabel in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Misconception.  You think that filtering a text file against a database table is going to be faster than just loading the entire file into the database.

I support there are extreme cases where this might be true.  But, in general, the safest way to handle these types of situation is:

- Import the file into a staging table.
- Add indexes, as necessary to the staging table for performance.
- Run a query to copy the data you want from the staging table.

I could phrase this a different way.  In the time it would take you to figure out how to efficient combine information from the file and a database table, you could probably go through the above process 10-50 times.